# git subtree внутри одного репозитория

Tags: git

Как слить содержимое папки ветки 1 в ветку 2 и поддерживать синхронность папки в ветке 1 и ветки 2?

**Контекст:**

Делаю библиотеку, в т.ч. для выкладывания на github.com, на github принято выкладывать master-ветки без файлов проекта и окружения (файл настроек ide, подтянутые зависимости и т.п.), я же привык всё таскать с собой, чтобы легко было восстановить окружение.

**Нужно сделать так:**

ветка env: моё рабочее окружение, вместе с подтянутыми зависимостями. Чтобы можно было просто сделать checkout и скомпилировать проект.

ветка master - только непосредственно мои исходники.

Речь идет о репизитории `https://github.com/rekby/mbr`, сейчас туда загружен вариант с веткой env. Ветка master пуста. В master должно быть содержимое `https://github.com/rekby/mbr/tree/env/src/github.com/rekby/mbr`

По документации я понял что мне хорошо должен подойти вариант поддеревьев (subtree) - я работаю в своей env-ветке и периодически сливаю изменения в мастер. При необходимости из master подтягиваю их обратно через
`git diff-tree`.

В этом месте возникла проблема - `git diff-tree` работает не так как я этого ожидаю.

Например:

```
git checkout env
git diff-tree -R -r -p master src/github.com/rekby/mbr
```

Как я понимаю должен мне выдать отличия в `src/github.com/rekby/mbr` ветки env (текущей) и корнем ветки master (в которой и должен оказаться мой код).
Вывод команды пуст.

Попробовал `с --relative` и еще несколько вариантов - результат тот же.

Comment: Вы представляете, сколько будет весить репозиторий? Не надо с собой окружение таскать, надо конфиг менеджера зависимостей корректно написать.

Comment: `.gitignore` с перечеслением всех "зависимостей" и "файлов настроек IDE" чем плох?

Comment: Размер репозитория представляю - мало. Зависимости - мелкие библиотеки, обычно тоже в исходниках. .gitignore не подходит т.к. при этом: 1. В репозиторий не будут пушиться зависимости, а надо. 2. будут длинные некрасивые пути, вместо того чтобы мой проект лежал сразу в корне мастер-ветки.

Comment: Собственно тягание зависимостей с собой - защита от удаления/поломки обратной совместимости во внешних репозиториях. Альтернатива - форкать всё подряд и плодить кучу своих репозиториев с зависимостями, но это неудобно, особенно при обновлениях зависимостей.

Comment: *работает не так как я этого ожидаю* — если я правильно понял ваши ожидания, то в приведённой команде после `master` надо вставить `env`: `git diff-tree -R -r -p master env src/github.com/rekby/mbr`

Comment: Эта команда видимо работает если пути к файлам одинаковые в обеих ветках. В моём случае они отличаются - пути в master на несколько папок короче, чем в env. Например если в master уже лежит то же что в env/src/github.com/rekby/mbr - команда всё равно выдает различия так же как если бы master был пуст.

Comment: В идеале мои ожидания: привести master в состояние env/src/.../mbr, при этом подтянуть комментарии из коммитов изменений с момента прошлого слияния.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотреть отличия в файлах, находящихся в разных каталогах в двух разных ветках можно так:

```
$ git diff branch1:path/num/1 branch2:path/num/2
```

в вашем конкретном случае примерно так:

```
$ git diff master: env:src/github.com/rekby/mbr
```

если достаточно просто перенести изменения в ветку `master`, то можно, переключившись в эту ветку, выполнить примерно такую команду:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git diff master: env:src/github.com/rekby/mbr | git apply
```

если же требуется перенести **коммиты** (т.е., коммит-сообщения, дату, авторство), то тогда следует ориентироваться не на различия в файлах (получаемые с помощью diff-а), а на различия в списке коммитов. придётся как-то самостоятельно отслеживать — какие коммиты уже перенесены, а какие ещё нет (я, к сожалению, не знаю средств git-а, позволяющих автоматизировать такой процесс — с изменением путей).

получить набор patch-файлов, содержащих коммиты, начиная с заданного, в вашем случае можно примерно так:

```
$ git checkout env
$ git format-patch хэш-последнего-уже-перенесённого-коммита
$ git checkout master
$ git am -p5 *.patch
```

обратите внимание на параметр `-p5` для команды `git am`. он указывает отбросить 5 элементов в пути файлов, перечисленных в патче, т.е. вместо `a/src/github.com/rekby/mbr/mbr.go` получится просто `mbr.go`.

не забудьте после этого удалить сформированные файлы *.patch, чтобы не возникло проблем при следующих переносах.

чтобы сформировать patch-файл для одного коммита, можно передать команде `git format-patch` параметр `-1`:

```
$ git format-patch -1 хэш-переносимого-коммита
```

Comment: Да, похоже на то что надо. Думаю что просто переносить изменения будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

возможно, лучшим решением (с сохранением предпочитаемого порядка работы) будет создание двух репозиториев: одного с кодом проекта и ещё одного с «дополнительной обвеской», в котором репозиторий с кодом будет подключен как подмодуль (submodule).

примерно так:

```
$ git checkout env
$ git submodule add url-репозитория-с-кодом путь/где/будет/находиться/подмодуль
$ git commit -m 'add submodule url-репозитория-с-кодом'
```

подробнее можно узнать в документации и примерах использования. например, [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Comment: На субмодули смотрел - это у меня как запасной вариант предполагается. Если с поддеревьями нормального решения не получится.